# Help understanding how the brackets are used... Rookie Question

Tags: php

I understand what the following line does but i don't understand how the brackets are used? I have always used brackets in an if, while and other statements but i have never used them in this fashion.

Are there rules to using them this way, should i not use them in this way? Any help would be appreciated... Thanks

```
${$key} = $temp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that specific case, there is effectively no difference between using brackets and not.

So your code is equivalent to the following:

```
$$key = $temp;
```

The brackets are typically used to force PHP to interpolate variables in strings, which isn't necessary in this case.

Using the brackets is very helpful for reducing ambiguity in a statement using array indices:

```
${$array[0]} = $temp;
```

As opposed to

```
$$array[0] = $temp;
```

The parser will think that you meant `($$array)[0]`, not `$($array[0])`

Comment: They can also be used to reduce ambiguity of array variable variables. "In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write $$a[1] then the parser needs to know if you meant to use $a[1] as a variable, or if you wanted $$a as the variable and then the [1] index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1]} for the first case and ${$a}[1] for the second." -http://il2.php.net/language.variables.variable

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- [Variable variables](http://il2.php.net/language.variables.variable)
- [Today I learned about PHP variable variables; "variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable". Also, variable](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/dst56/today_i_learned_about_php_variable_variables/)

Comment: @Jacob Relkin. But the OP doesn't understand how the brackets are used and if there rules to using them this way. The links provided give some insight into this.

Comment: Thanks, the second link was helpful. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be using [variable variables](http://codepad.org/ogDleWRr).

Otherwise, braces like that are usually used for variable interpolation in strings, where the variable is an object property or array member.

In the example above, they are not necessary. [It also seems you can subscript an array with variable variables, with no issues](http://codepad.org/1IWDhY9p).